# How to create an internet protocol like HTTPS?

Tags: internet, transport-protocol

If I want to create my own internet protocol, what should I do? How can I create it?

Will people be able to use my protocol in their internet browsers? I asked this question in a simple Discord server and they said **"Your internet browser must support that."**. What happens if my internet browser doesn't support it?

Let's say I created my protocol. How it'll be secured like HTTPS? I mean, when you enter websites that doesn't use HTTPS or HTTP, it gives you a basic error about that.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off-topic here. There are innumerable application-layer protocols, both published and proprietary. Simply look at the _[IANA Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)_.

Comment: @RonMaupin Maupin, where do we find the list of on or off topic subject matters for this stackexchange site?

Comment: @MoeSzyslak See the [help] for which question can be asked here.

Comment: Every SE site has a [tour] and a [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, and you are expected to be familiar with those prior to posting on the site.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thank you for answering. Then I just want to ask a simple question. If I can make that protocol myself for example "hyper://", will I be able to use it like HTTPS if I design it in that way? Do you know anything about that?

Comment: You should ask about security on [security.se] (it's not nearly as easy as you may think), and an application (browser) must be coded to use your protocol, but most browsers use Open Source code, so you could roll your own browser to use the protocol.